# Passing Parameter to URL ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was just wondering what the best practice is for passing a parameter into a URL that contains characters that you do not wish to pass to the URL. For example, I pass the string `/LM/W3SVC/7/ROOT` into the URL but I want to pass it without the backslashes, thus like `LMW3SVC7ROOT`

The way I currently do this is by using `.Replace()`. This is the full line of code that I currently use `<a href="@Url.Action("Errors", new { id=item.Application.Replace("/", "").Replace(".", "")})"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Application) </a>` which works fine but throws out a warning every now and again so I was just wondering if this is the correct way of implementing it.

`'Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type 'string'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should URL encode it with the backslashes in, or is there a specific reason for not wanting to do that?

Comment: What is the type of `item.Application`? Is it a string?

Comment: No there is no reason for not using that, maybe because of a lack of knowledge if anything. And yes it is a string @jumpingcode

Comment: Is the error coming from your `Url.Action`?

Comment: No, its actually coming from my controller on this line of code `var queryString = RouteData.Values["id"];`

`var applications = db.ElmahErrors.Where(s => s.Application.Replace("/", "").Replace(".", "") == queryString)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're getting is from `var queryString = RouteData.Values["id"];`. If you look in Visual Studio and hover over `var` it will tell you the type of that particular `var`, which in this case is `Object`.

Try:

```
var queryString = RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
```

In this case, you're finding yourself having to replace certain characters in your string, which probably means server side, you might be having to do some extra logic to cope without having these characters on the received string. In your View, just wrap the `id` in `Url.Encode`:

```
id = Url.Encode(item.Application)
```

You will receive this server side with the string decoded, i.e. `/LM/W3SVC/7/ROOT`

Comment: Thanks, this gets rid of the warning, but is it better I use `URL Encode` over `.Replace()` in future or does it not really matter?

Comment: @D.M I updated my answer, just thought I'd help with the error first.